# Why Data gets leaked into sibling Instance of Component when Removed vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am building with following scenario. Parent creates multi instances of a child component. Each child holds its data via input field. Child can ask to be removed and parent removes that instance. so far so good. So now is the problem, as soon as that instance is removed, its data gets passed/leaked to next sibling instance and if that instance is holding data, it gets moved to other next-to-it instance. I have reproduced it on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lahori/v0z02cna/4/)

or see below

```js
    Vue.component('child', {
     props:['data'],
        template: `
            <div>
                index# {{data}}: {{messages}}
                <input type="text" v-model="text" @keypress.enter="addMessage" placeholder="add some data then delete it">
                <button @click="addMessage">Add</button>
                <button @click="$emit('delete-me')">Delete</button>
            </div>`,
            data() {
             return {
               messages:[],
                text: ''
              }
            },
            methods: {
             addMessage() {
               this.messages.push(this.text)
                this.text = ''
              }
            }
    })
    
    Vue.component('parent', {
        template: `
            <div>
                Keep Adding new Instances 
                <button @click="newChild">New</button>
                <hr />
                <child v-for="(child, index) in children" key="index"
                v-on:delete-me="deleteThisRow(index)""
                :data="child"
                ></child>
            </div>`,
            data() {
             return {
               children:[]
              }
        },
        methods: {
         newChild() {
           this.children.push(this.children.length)
          },
          deleteThisRow(index) {
                this.children.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    })
    
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        template: `
            <div>
              <parent />
                
            </div>
        `,
        
        methods: {
            
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two mistakes in here:

1. `:key` instead of `key`

**Reason**: Since dynamic values can change, so Vue should know about that change to 
 keep itself updated

2. child instead of `index`

**Reason:** Not sure about this but may be Because Vue already holds its own copy of indices in Virtual DOM so it needs values only